# Event propagation when many children and options in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to web development. I started with AngularJS and maybe learnt bad practices because Angular makes it convenient to put javascript into HTML.

With AngularJS, I used to write:

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        { name:"item 1" },
        { name:"item 2" }
    ];
    $scope.remove = function(item) {
        var i = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
        $scope.items.splice(i,1);
    };
    $scope.log = function(item) {
        console.log(item.name);
    };
});
```

With my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item.name}}
      <button class="log" ng-click="log(item)">log</button>
      <button class="remove" ng-click="remove(item)">remove</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I read today about event propagation and I like its principle.
But in practice, I come up with something like:

```
var list = document.body;
list.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var i = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.children).indexOf(e.target);
    switch(target.className){
        "log": break; // call $scope.log here
        "remove": break; // call $scope.remove here
    }
});
```

Is it possible to make my handlers more specific to avoid the big switch?

Comment: Actually thats always a bit ugly in plain js. In jquery one could do `$(window).on("click", ".remove", removeHandler)`

Comment: The purpose of a framework like AngularJS is to prevent you from having to create eventListeners manually like you are doing above.

Comment: OK thanks! So no magic solution. I already moved from controllers to directives, now I'm thinking just to move out of angular ^^

Comment: @JonasW. I also want the handler to adapt dynamically when new items are created (or attach new listeners to new items). Would it be still feasible with jquery?

Comment: @raphamex the code i have included does so